# How are 'comments' tied to 'article' in django-comments package?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-generic-relations

In Django's own comment framework, **[django-contrib-comments](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments)**, if I create my own comment model as below:

```
from django_comments.models import Comment

class MyCommentModel(Comment):
```

**Q: How should I associate this new comment model (`MyCommentModel`) with existing `Article` model? using attribute `content_type`, `object_pk` or `content_object` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use it directly like this:

```
article = Article.objects.get(id=1)
comment = MyCommentModel(content_object=article, comment='my comment')
comment.save()
```

But if you want to access the comments from `Article`, you can use [**`GenericRelation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation


class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = GenericRelation(MyCommentModel)

article = Article.objects.get(id=1)
article.comments.all()
```